# ajax load method and the title of the page

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I'm big newbie to ajax
I followed some tutorials and this was my result

```
(function(){

    $('#nav li a').on('click', function(e){

        e.preventDefault();
        var href = $(this).attr('href');

        $('#content').load(href+' #content');
        $('title').load(href+' title');
        $('#nav').load(href+' #nav');
    });

})();
```

the output of title for this code is

`<title><title>About Us!</title></title>`

and this was the output for the nav code

```
<ul id="nav"><ul id="nav">
        <li><a href="index.html">Index</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.html" class="hover">about</a></li>
        <li><a href="portfolio.html">portfolio</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="terms.html">terms</a></li>
    </ul></ul>
```

and there is a better way to load more than element, title and navbar and content?

Comment: Can you give sample code on jsfiddle.net?

Comment: @rahulmaindargi how to add code in jsfiddle useful and working with ajax method?

Comment: have you looked at the [`load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/#loading-page-fragments) documentation? you can only load page fragments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
(function(){

    $('#nav li a').on('click', function(e){

        e.preventDefault();
        var href = $(this).attr('href');

        $.ajax({
            url: href,
            dataType: 'html'
        }).done(function(html){
            var $html = $(html);
            $('#content').replaceWith($html.find('#content'));
            $('title').html($html.filter('title').text());
            $('#nav').replaceWith($html.find('#nav'));
        });

    });

})();
```

using `replaceWith` will remove the two times  or  tags

As per comment I dont know why `on` or `live` will not work on it... 
but as an alternative you can do this...

(function(){
        function test(e){

```
        e.preventDefault();
        var href = $(this).attr('href');

        $.ajax({
            url: href,
            dataType: 'html'
        }).done(function(html){
            var $html = $(html);
            $('#content').replaceWith($html.find('#content'));
            $('title').html($html.filter('title').text());
            $('#nav').replaceWith($html.find('#nav'));
            $('#nav li a').on('click',test );
        });

    }

    $('#nav li a').on('click',test );

})();
```

Comment: after nav replaced With new nav, ajax not applied on new links on nav, i tried to use live instead of on, but it doesn't work with jq 1.9, Thanks

Comment: I dont know why on or live will not work on it... but as an alternative you can try above alternate code

Comment: Now working gr8 with content and nav, but unfortunately title still not working, Thank you so much :)

Comment: See updated answer 
`$html.filter('title').text()` check and let me know if it works...Accept if it works

Comment: just one step and we done all :), the result now is the title without the tag <title>

Comment: I tried to wrap it with wrap() but i don't know where i should add it

Comment: Make sure `$('title').html($html.filter('title').text());` and not `$('title').replaceWith($html.filter('title').text());` html will have title tag.. if you use `replaceWith` only text will remain..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29582/discussion-between-jimmy-todd-and-rahul-maindargi)

Comment: oh, sorry i didn't mean to chat with you just was testing the link under our comments,, "Please avoid extended discussions in comments. Would you like to automatically move this discussion to chat?"

Answer (score 2):

In this case you are loading the resource three times

```
(function(){

    $('#nav li a').on('click', function(e){

        e.preventDefault();
        var href = $(this).attr('href');

        $.ajax({
            url: href,
            dataType: 'html'
        }).done(function(html){
            var $html = $(html);
            $('#content').html($html.find('#content').unwrap());
            $('title').html($html.find('title').unwrap());
            $('#nav').html($html.find('#nav').unwrap());
        });

    });

})();
```

Comment: Thank you, the title output blank,, and the output of the nav the same problem i have, wrapping the ul twice <ul id="nav"><ul id="nav">

Comment: the result now both blank title and nav, but the content now wrapping twice <div id="content"><div id="content">